# Wordle Pictionary!

Tags: chess, wordle

Inspired by the new game of Wordle, I have created a new type of puzzle combining Wordle and Pictionary.

The left image represents a phrase of six five-letter words. Normal Wordle rules apply: Green squares indicate the correct letter in the correct position and Yellow squares indicate the correct letter in the wrong position (unless it is “counterfeited” by a duplicate letter in the same word). Obviously the six-word phrase does not necessarily represent proper strategy in an actual Wordle game and the player got extremely lucky with his or her final guess!

Example: If a player guesses EERIE and the correct word is STEAK then only the first ‘E’ is highlighted yellow. Of course, green squares can never be counterfeited.

The right image represents a visual hint for the six-word phrase (so think something like "rebus" or "Pictionary")

**Your task is to identify the six-word phrase from the clues given**

This puzzle is not intended to be difficult. I am hoping this will inspire more challenging puzzles on the same theme if other PSE folk like the concept 
[image]

Comment: Nice little puzzle!

Comment: Pure brilliance.

Answer (score 13):

This does not appear to be a good strategy at all.

> WHITE
> QUEEN
> TAKES
> BLACK
> HORSE (knight)
> CHECK

Comment: That is correct. Too easy!

Comment: Not a very good Wordle strategy for sure, but definitely the only way to win the chess game on the spot.

Comment: @Bass not that either (replace the white knight with a bishop, and it should be).  But improving the chess aspect would mean finishing on a 4-letter word

Comment: @ChrisH:  If the white knight is replaced by a bishop, black can still play Kg8 after the capture.  White can then mate with Qg7

Comment: @RossMillikan yes, but with the white knight black can do Kxf6 which they couldn't with a bishop (the puzzle would still hold true anyway).  Getting OT now but I reckon (and I haven't played chess in decades) rather than Kg8, play Kf8, at least to spin things out a bit longer

Comment: @ChrisH I'm not sure what you are trying to say. Are you maybe missing the royal fork white has planned as the follow-up?

Comment: @Bass with the knight? I discounted it

Comment: Well, don't discount the only winning move so quickly, then. :-)