# Wordle Pictionary Puzzle 2

Tags: knowledge, music, wordle

This was inspired by some < ahem> sub-optimal guessing strategy < / ahem > by one of my Stand-up comedian friends. The basic concept is the solver must guess a multi-word phrase using a Wordle clue and a Pictionary clue, as described [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114519/wordle-pictionary/).

Again, I do not expect this to be difficult – but some general knowledge may help 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Juicy Juicy Green Grass", Peter Combe

which I found by simply

> searching the Web for the lyrics in the picture.